# AssemblyVersion with * just generates "0.0"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 to build a C# `Class Library`. The assembly has an AssemblyInfo.cs file with these attributes:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.0.0.0")]
```

In `.csproj`, the `Deterministic` tag was set to `false`, the project was then reloaded and rebuilt. Right-click the assembly and `Properties > Details` shows:

- File version = 8.0.0.0
- Product version = 8.0.0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Ideally `File version` would have the format `8.0.BUILD.REVISION` with BUILD the days since 2000-01-01 and REVISION half the seconds since 00:00. And `Product version` would be just `8.0.0.0`. Is this possible?

#### Update

After some experimentation, commenting out `AssemblyFileVersion`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.0.0.0")]
```

gives part of the answer. Now `Properties > Details` shows:

- File version = 8.0.7710.25829
- Product version = 8.0.7710.25829

Progress! But is there a way to have an auto-generated BUILD and REVISION for `File version` but to have a fixed `Product version`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @MarkBenningfield did not work for me, but prompted me to experiment. Here's the solution that gave the result I needed. In AssemblyInfo.cs, set the lines to:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("8.0.0.0")]
```

(and set `Deterministic` to "false" in the .csproj file).

Now the assembly builds with auto-generated BUILD and REVISION for `File version`, while displaying the `Product version` with my fixed string.

Visual Studio gives you the tags `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` by default for new projects. You need to swap `AssemblyFileVersion` for `AssemblyInformationalVersion`.

[image: File and Product version]

Answer (score 0):

You've got it turned around. Use

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("8.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("8.0.*")] // older versions of VS use full asterisks ("8.0.*.*")
```

This will give you a fixed version for the assembly, and let you track build increments with the file version.

Comment: Not working for me. Now `File version` is `8.0.0.0` and `Product version` is `8.0.*.*` (as reported by Windows > Explorer > Properties > Details).

Comment: Did you make any changes to the source code prior to the last build?

Comment: Yes, and `Build > Clean Solution`, then `Build > Rebuild All` just to be sure. After a bit of experimentation, commenting out the `AssemblyFileVersion` line and setting `AssemblyVersion` to "8.0.*" gives `File version` and `Product version` with auto-generated BUILD and REVISION. But it would be good if `File version` was automatically generated, but `Product version` was fixed.

Comment: Well, on my machine, using the asterisks on FileVersion does just that. However, it only uses a simple increment, and only if the source code is edited. If you want custom incrementation (e.g. days since 2001-01-01) you'll have to use some pre-build processing.

Comment: Well, if I comment out `AssemblyFileVersion` then I do get the Visual Studio style file versions. After rebuilding a minute ago, my `File version` is `8.0.7710.25829`.

Comment: But, putting the asterisk in `FileVersion` and using literals for `AssemblyVersion` dosn't?

Comment: Do you mean `FileVersion` or `AssemblyFileVersion`? There is no `FileVersion` attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. I'll try manually adding that and see what happens...no just tried it and `FileVersion` is not a valid attribute (project doesn't build).

Comment: Stumbled on the answer! There is an attribute called `AssemblyInformationalVersion` that needs to be set. Will knock that up into an answer...thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228471/discussion-between-mark-benningfield-and-alaind).